# Why is my EntityManager null in my Quartz Job on Wildfly 10?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, wildfly-10

I'm trying to implement a batch upload job in my app running on Wildfly 10.  I want to create a Quartz job that will download some files and load them in the database.  However when my job runs the entitymanager is always null.  How can I get my entity manger injected in this case?  I wrote the following code that simplifies my situation as much as possible.  Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

@Stateless
public class DownloadService implements Job {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        if (entityManager == null) {
            System.out.println("############## entityManager is null ####");
        } else
            System.out.println("************** WORKING ***************");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you scanned this class using `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package"/>.`